# Heroku Couldn`t find that formation,Scaling dyons

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... failed
Couldn't find that formation.

when im trying to deploy new app this error is shown on console.
and i really dont understand Ensure that at least one instance of the app is running.?

Comment: Exact same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513295/couldnt-find-that-formation-heroku-deployment-error), does it help?